# Power BI DAX: How to calculate the sum of a row for distinct date only

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am currently updating this dax to make sure that I am getting the correct value from table2durationhours column - this is a calculated column from another table. However, when I use this dax it sum up all the rows from table2durationhours resulting to very large hours for 1 date. For example, there are multiple rows for 06/05/2022 and it sum up all of these, and it should be for 1 row only. Please see below dax I am currently using:

Week 1:

```
Week1Duration = VAR SelectedWeekStart = SELECTEDVALUE('01_Date'[Start of Week]) VAR Week1StartDate = CALCULATE(MIN('01_Date'[CalendarDate]), '01_Date'[Start of Week] = SelectedWeekStart) VAR Week1EndDate = Week1StartDate + 6 RETURN CALCULATE( SUM(FactTable[Table2DurationHours]), 'FactTable'[Date] >= Week1StartDate && 'FactTable'[Date] <= Week1EndDate )
```

Week 2:

```
Week2Duration = CALCULATE(SUM('FactTable'[Table2DurationHours]), REMOVEFILTERS('01_Date'[Start of Week]), '01_Date'[Week ID] = MAX('01_Date'[Week ID]) + 1)
```

Sample Table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to sum the hours worked by week? (I'm not completely clear, but reading between the lines, that's what it appears.) The easiest way to do this is to create a calendar table... you can use code like this:

```
DimDate =
```

ADDCOLUMNS(
CALENDAR(
MINX('WorkData',[Date]),
MAXX('WorkData',[Date])
),
"Year",YEAR([Date]),
"MonthNo",MONTH([Date]),
"Month",FORMAT([Date],"MMM"),
"Weekday",FORMAT([Date],"DDD"),
"DayOfWeek",WEEKDAY([Date]),
"WeekOfYear",WEEKNUM([Date]),
"Day",DAY([Date]))

Then you can do something simple in a matrix. Put "WeekOfYear" on ROWS and "DurationHours" on VALUES, and you'll get a sum by default of the total hours by weeknumber. I think that's what you were asking - if not, please clarify.